# K-means clustering, changing colour of data to depending on closest centroid

Tags: python, k-means

My python code below performs a very very simple K-means clustering on a set of data. The issue that exists is that I need the colour of the data points to change depending on which centroid it is closest too. Can anyone help me with what I should do?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def calc_dist_euclidean(vec_1, vec_2):

    distances = np.sqrt(((vec_1 - vec_2[:, np.newaxis]) ** 2).sum(axis=2))
    dist_euclidean = np.argmin(distances, axis=0)

    return dist_euclidean


def init_cent(dataset, k):

    centroids = dataset.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(centroids)

    return centroids[:k]


def k_means(dataset, k):

    centroids = init_cent(dataset, k)

    distances = calc_dist_euclidean(dataset, centroids)

    cluster_assigning = np.array([dataset[distances == k].mean(axis=0) for k in range(centroids.shape[0])])

    return centroids, cluster_assigning


df = pd.read_csv('bristol_vacation_rentals_2016.csv')

dataset = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values

k = 3

centroids, cluster_assigning = k_means(dataset, k)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], s=2)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],  c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.ylabel('longitude')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], s=2)
plt.scatter(cluster_assigning[:, 0], cluster_assigning[:, 1], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.ylabel('longitude')
plt.show()
```

Comment: By the way, it would be easier for us if you provide sampling data in your code. Instead of loading the dataset from an unprovided csv file, substitute it for something like: dataset = np.random.rand(100).reshape(50, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it easay, I would reuse the variable `distances` from `k_means()` function, returning it:

```
def k_means(dataset, k):

    centroids = init_cent(dataset, k)

    distances = calc_dist_euclidean(dataset, centroids)

    cluster_assigning = np.array([dataset[distances == k].mean(axis=0) for k in range(centroids.shape[0])])

    return centroids, distances, cluster_assigning
```

Then, you can plot your centroids and data points based on corresponding cluster defining a numpy array `colors` containing each color and creating a numpy array of colors for each of your data points using `colors[distances]`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bristol_vacation_rentals_2016.csv')

dataset = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values

k = 3
colors = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])

centroids, distances, cluster_assigning = k_means(dataset, k)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], c=colors[distances], s=2)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],  c=colors, s=50)
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.ylabel('longitude')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], c=colors[distances], s=2)
plt.scatter(cluster_assigning[:, 0], cluster_assigning[:, 1], c=colors, s=50)
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.ylabel('longitude')
plt.show()
```